# WPF TabItem format date

Tags: wpf, mvvm, string-formatting, tabitem

I am trying to create a style for a TabControl to achieve 2 goals:

1. Display the selected TabItem with a different background color and in bold.
2. Format the tab header text, bound to a date in the view model, to hours and minutes like "15:45".

I almost succeeded but the header text is also displaying the date part.
Besides it is displaying 03:45 instead of 15:45.

[see screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghISn.png)

Here is the XAML code I am using:

```
    <TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding MC}" >
        <TabControl.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#01535F" />
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Azure" />
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16" />
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black" />
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="TabItem">
                            <Border Name="Border" BorderThickness="1,1,1,0" BorderBrush="Black" Margin="1,1">
                                <Grid Name="Panel">
                                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentSite"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                    ContentSource="Header"
                                    />
                                    <!--<HeaderedContentControl Header="{Binding Path=MarketStartTime, StringFormat={}{0:HH:mm}}" />-->
                                </Grid>
                            </Border>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                                    <Setter TargetName="Panel" Property="Background" Value="#003F44" />
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="False">
                                    <Setter TargetName="Panel" Property="Background" Value="#01535F" />
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                                </Trigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <HeaderedContentControl Header="{Binding Path=MarketStartTime, StringFormat={}{0:HH:mm}}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </TabControl.Resources>
    </TabControl>
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: "HH" *is* the format string for the 24 hour clock so are you sure your time is 15:45 and not actually 3:45?

Comment: Yes I was sure, I did the screenshot at the same time I asked the question. Using the ItemTemplate as suggested in the accepted answer fixed this issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding MC}">
    <TabControl.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#01535F" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Azure" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="TabItem">
                        <Border Name="Border" BorderThickness="1,1,1,0" BorderBrush="Black" Margin="1,1">
                            <Grid Name="Panel">
                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentSite" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" ContentSource="Header" />
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                                <Setter TargetName="Panel" Property="Background" Value="#003F44" />
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="False">
                                <Setter TargetName="Panel" Property="Background" Value="#01535F" />
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </TabControl.Resources>

    <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=MarketStartTime, StringFormat={}{0:HH:mm}}"></TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

The `ItemTemplate` is for the header area, the `ContentTemplate` is for what is showing in the content area. That `ContentPresenter` in the `ContentTemplate` will instantiate the controls from the `ItemTemplate`.

Comment: I still have 2 questions, I am a bit confused with the control template that is used for the header content. I would like to add a padding in the tab header so that the text is not too close to the border and create a data template for the tab content with a listbox. I don't understand where to put the XAML code for theses 2 changes.